# I can't connect MySQL DB in symfony 1.0

Tags: php, database, symfony1, mamp, propel

I use symfony1.0.22. on localhost,on MAMP.
studying with askeet ,I can't move...

I can't connect mySQL DB… 
it say "no such file or directry".
I can't understand WHAT IT SAYING!

log is below.Please tell me what I can do…

```
>     symfony propel-insert-sql
>     >> schema    converting "/Applications/MAMP/..._fail/config/schema.yml" to XML
>     >> schema    putting /Applications/MAMP/htdo...ail/config/generated-schema.xml Buildfile:
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build.xml
> [resolvepath] Resolved /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config
> to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config
>     
>     propel-project-builder > check-project-or-dir-set:
>     
>     propel-project-builder > check-project-set:
>     
>     propel-project-builder > set-project-dir:
>     
>     propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-exists:
>     
>     propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-for-propel-gen:
>     
>     propel-project-builder > check-buildprops:
>     
>     propel-project-builder > configure:
>          [echo] Loading project-specific props from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config/propel.ini  [property]
> Loading /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config/propel.ini
>     
>     propel-project-builder > insert-sql:
>         [phing] Calling Buildfile '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml'
> with target 'insert-sql'  [property] Loading
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/./default.properties
>     
>     propel > insert-sql: [propel-sql-exec] Executing statements in file:
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/data/sql/lib.model.schema.sql
> [propel-sql-exec] Our new url -> mysql://root:root@localhost/iii
> Execution of target "insert-sql" failed for the following reason:
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml:296:1:
> [wrapped: connect failed [Native Error: No such file or directory]
> [User Info: Array]]
>         [phing] /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml:296:1:
> [wrapped: connect failed [Native Error: No such file or directory]
> [User Info: Array]]
>     
>     BUILD FINISHED
>     
>     Total time: 0.3183 seconds
>     >> file-     /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch...ail/config/generated-schema.xml
```

P.S. and propel.ini is below.

```
>         propel.targetPackage       = lib.model
>         propel.packageObjectModel  = true
>         propel.project             = sf_fail
>         propel.database            = mysql
>         #propel.database.createUrl  = mysql://root:root@localhost/
>         propel.database.url        = mysql://root:root@localhost/sf_fail
>         
>         propel.addGenericAccessors = true
>         propel.addGenericMutators  = true
>         propel.addTimeStamp        = false
>         
>         propel.schema.validate     = false
>         propel.mysql.tableType = InnoDB
>         
>         ; directories
>         propel.home                    = .
>         propel.output.dir              = /var/www/symfony/sf_fail
>         propel.schema.dir              = ${propel.output.dir}/config
>         propel.conf.dir                = ${propel.output.dir}/config
>         propel.phpconf.dir             = ${propel.output.dir}/config
>         propel.sql.dir                 = ${propel.output.dir}/data/sql
>         propel.runtime.conf.file       = runtime-conf.xml
>         propel.php.dir                 = ${propel.output.dir}
>         propel.default.schema.basename = schema
>         propel.datadump.mapper.from    = *schema.xml
>         propel.datadump.mapper.to      = *data.xml
>         
>         ; builder settings
>         propel.builder.peer.class              = addon.propel.builder.SfPeerBuilder
>         propel.builder.object.class            = addon.propel.builder.SfObjectBuilder
>         
>         propel.builder.objectstub.class        = addon.propel.builder.SfExtensionObjectBuilder
>         propel.builder.peerstub.class          = addon.propel.builder.SfExtensionPeerBuilder
>         propel.builder.objectmultiextend.class = addon.propel.builder.SfMultiExtendObjectBuilder
>         propel.builder.mapbuilder.class        = addon.propel.builder.SfMapBuilderBuilder
>         propel.builder.interface.class         = propel.engine.builder.om.php5.PHP5InterfaceBuilder
>         propel.builder.node.class              = propel.engine.builder.om.php5.PHP5NodeBuilder
>         propel.builder.nodepeer.class          = propel.engine.builder.om.php5.PHP5NodePeerBuilder
>         propel.builder.nodestub.class          = propel.engine.builder.om.php5.PHP5ExtensionNodeBuilder
>         propel.builder.nodepeerstub.class      = propel.engine.builder.om.php5.PHP5ExtensionNodePeerBuilder
>         
>         propel.builder.addIncludes = false
>         propel.builder.addComments = false
>         
>         propel.builder.addBehaviors = false
```

What I did before I encounter this problem

install symfony1.0.22 in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/ by pear

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/pear /usr/bin/pear
$ pear upgrade PEAR 
$ pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
$ pear install symfony-1.0.22
$ sudo ln -s -f /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/symfony /usr/bin/symfony
```

and I made dir named 'sf_fail' in /Application/MAMP

```
$cd /Application/MAMP/sf_fail
$symfony init-project sf_fail
$symfony init-app frontend
```

next,I edit shema.yml,database.yml,propel.ini to create DB. and I made DB by MAMP's phpMyAdmin ,named 'sf_fail'.

```
$symfony propel-build-model
$symfony propel-build-sql
```

I think,there is no problem until below command.

```
$symfony propel-insert-sql
```

this can't move uhmm...
I just added resulut of "propel-build-all" for more infomation.

```
>         symfony propel-build-all
>         >> schema    converting "/Applications/MAMP/..._fail/config/schema.yml" to XML
>         >> schema    putting /Applications/MAMP/htdo...ail/config/generated-schema.xml
>         Buildfile: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build.xml
>         [resolvepath] Resolved /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config to
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-project-or-dir-set:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-project-set:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > set-project-dir:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-exists:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-for-propel-gen:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > configure:
>              [echo] Loading project-specific props from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config/propel.ini
>          [property] Loading /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config/propel.ini
>         
>         propel-project-builder > om:
>             [phing] Calling Buildfile '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml'
> with target 'om'
>          [property] Loading /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/./default.properties
>         
>         propel > check-run-only-on-schema-change:
>         
>         propel > om-check:
>         
>         propel > om:
>              [echo] +------------------------------------------+
>              [echo] |                                          |
>              [echo] | Generating Peer-based Object Model for   |
>              [echo] | YOUR Propel project! (NEW OM BUILDERS)!  |
>              [echo] |                                          |
>              [echo] +------------------------------------------+
>         [phingcall] Calling Buildfile '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml'
> with target 'om-template'
>          [property] Loading /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/./default.properties
>         
>         propel > om-template:
>         [PHP Error] strftime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
> or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
> those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
> misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Tokyo' for
> 'JST/9.0/no DST' instead [line 539 of
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/classes/propel/phing/AbstractPropelDataModelTask.php]
>         [propel-om] Target database type: mysql
>         [propel-om] Target package: lib.model
>         [propel-om] Using template path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/templates
>         [propel-om] Output directory: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail
>         [propel-om] Processing: generated-schema.xml
>         [propel-om] Processing Datamodel : JoinedDataModel
>         [propel-om]   - processing database : propel
>         [propel-om]   + user
>         [propel-om]       -> BaseUserPeer [builder: SfPeerBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> BaseUser [builder: SfObjectBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> UserMapBuilder [builder: SfMapBuilderBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> (exists) UserPeer
>         [propel-om]       -> (exists) User
>         [propel-om]   + tag
>         [propel-om]       -> BaseTagPeer [builder: SfPeerBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> BaseTag [builder: SfObjectBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> TagMapBuilder [builder: SfMapBuilderBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> (exists) TagPeer
>         [propel-om]       -> (exists) Tag
>         [propel-om]   + photo
>         [propel-om]       -> BasePhotoPeer [builder: SfPeerBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> BasePhoto [builder: SfObjectBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> PhotoMapBuilder [builder: SfMapBuilderBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> (exists) PhotoPeer
>         [propel-om]       -> (exists) Photo
>         [propel-om]   + idle
>         [propel-om]       -> BaseIdlePeer [builder: SfPeerBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> BaseIdle [builder: SfObjectBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> IdleMapBuilder [builder: SfMapBuilderBuilder]
>         [propel-om]       -> (exists) IdlePeer
>         [propel-om]       -> (exists) Idle
>         
>         BUILD FINISHED
>         
>         Total time: 1.5223 second
>         >> file-     /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch...ail/config/generated-schema.xml
>         >> schema    converting "/Applications/MAMP/..._fail/config/schema.yml" to XML
>         >> schema    putting /Applications/MAMP/htdo...ail/config/generated-schema.xml
>         Buildfile: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build.xml
>         [resolvepath] Resolved /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config to
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-project-or-dir-set:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-project-set:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > set-project-dir:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-exists:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-for-propel-gen:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > configure:
>              [echo] Loading project-specific props from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config/propel.ini
>          [property] Loading /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config/propel.ini
>         
>         propel-project-builder > sql:
>             [phing] Calling Buildfile '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml'
> with target 'sql'
>          [property] Loading /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/./default.properties
>         
>         propel > check-run-only-on-schema-change:
>         
>         propel > sql-check:
>         
>         propel > pgsql-quoting-check:
>         
>         propel > sql:
>              [echo] +------------------------------------------+
>              [echo] |                                          |
>              [echo] | Generating SQL for YOUR Propel project!  |
>              [echo] |                                          |
>              [echo] +------------------------------------------+
>         [phingcall] Calling Buildfile '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml'
> with target 'sql-template'
>          [property] Loading /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/./default.properties
>         
>         propel > sql-template:
>         [propel-sql] Processing: generated-schema.xml
>         [propel-sql] Writing to SQL file: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/data/sql/lib.model.schema.sql
>         [propel-sql]  + user [builder: MysqlDDLBuilder]
>         [propel-sql]  + tag [builder: MysqlDDLBuilder]
>         [propel-sql]  + photo [builder: MysqlDDLBuilder]
>         [propel-sql]  + idle [builder: MysqlDDLBuilder]
>         
>         BUILD FINISHED
>         
>         Total time: 0.3328 seconds
>         >> file-     /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch...ail/config/generated-schema.xml
>         >> schema    converting "/Applications/MAMP/..._fail/config/schema.yml" to XML
>         >> schema    putting /Applications/MAMP/htdo...ail/config/generated-schema.xml
>         Buildfile: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build.xml
>         [resolvepath] Resolved /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config to
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-project-or-dir-set:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-project-set:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > set-project-dir:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-exists:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-for-propel-gen:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > check-buildprops:
>         
>         propel-project-builder > configure:
>              [echo] Loading project-specific props from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config/propel.ini
>          [property] Loading /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/config/propel.ini
>         
>         propel-project-builder > insert-sql:
>             [phing] Calling Buildfile '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml'
> with target 'insert-sql'
>          [property] Loading /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/./default.properties
>         
>         propel > insert-sql:
>         [propel-sql-exec] Executing statements in file: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch/sf_fail/data/sql/lib.model.schema.sql
>         [propel-sql-exec] Our new url -> mysql://root:root@localhost/sf_fail
>         Execution of target "insert-sql" failed for the following reason:
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml:296:1:
> [wrapped: connect failed [Native Error: No such file or directory]
> [User Info: Array]]
>             [phing] /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/symfony/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml:296:1:
> [wrapped: connect failed [Native Error: No such file or directory]
> [User Info: Array]]
>     
>     BUILD FINISHED
>     
>     Total time: 0.1648 seconds
>     >> file-     /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hatch...ail/config/generated-schema.xml
```

Comment: Symfony 1.0 is vastly out of date. If you need to start with Symfony, either use the 1.4 stable release which is supported until November 2012, or (preferably) shift to Symfony2.

Comment: Also, do some web-searching around 'propel 1.2 no such file or directory' - I got [this](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=22873).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info (although it would make much more sense if you split it out into several <pre> blocks). Did the suggestions in my link above help out at all? There were a lot of suggestions in there.

Comment: >richsage thx for editing!!
but I did't figure out...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the error messages in Propel 1.2 (the bundled version) could do with being a bit more helpful, that's for sure. It also doesn't use PDO, and so is much slower than recent versions. I'd recommend that you bump up to at least Symfony 1.3, which has a much better version of Propel installed.

@richsage recommends Symfony 1.4, but the forms system that that enforces - in my humble opinion - was vastly over-complicated. Symfony 1.3 has it also, but at least there you can switch to 10compatibility mode (I forget exactly what it is called) - and this lets you return to the component helpers approach. Also, you can upgrade your version of Propel right up to 1.6 in Symfony 1.3 (or 1.4) by adding a plugin.

Comment: thx for answer! but I must do it on Symfony 1.0.22, because my company use 1.0... X(

Comment: OK; can you add the contents of your `propel.ini` to the question? Also let us know what other commands you've used prior to this.

Comment: (Don't forget that if you are constrained internally by the rule 'we only use software X', as a developer it is your responsibility to make the case for upgrading. No-one else is going to lobby for the technical changes you need)

Comment: Sorry,I can't use well this system...
just I add new infomation.

Comment: Bah! Spotted it - change `propel.output.dir` from `/var/www/symfony/sf_fail` to `/Application/MAMP/sf_fail` - think that's it.

Comment: (By the way, why is your propel.ini prefixed on every line with a `>`? It's not really like that, is it? `:-O`)

Comment: It is because I can't use well editer of this website...
quote?? code??

Comment: and I can't use English well too... so sorry X(

Comment: No worries - let me know how you get on with the above fix for `propel.output.dir`.

Comment: Why does it not make sense? Your replies are generally not giving a lot to respond to.

Comment: I can't understand . but it seems to no effect...because error messages didn't change.
I'll try uninstall it all,and reinstall it.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using a reasonably up-to-date version of PHP 5.2 (I think the minimum is 5.2.4, but ideally you should use 5.2.17 i.e. the latest). Not sure whether symfony 1.0.x it will run on PHP 5.3.x.

Comment: Another suggestion that often helped me with Symfony1.0/Propel1.2/Oracle - don't be afraid to put debug statements deep inside Symfony or Propel, to debug it just like another other PHP system. I worked out what connection string formats worked for Oracle that way!

Comment: Lastly, I wouldn't bother with PEAR - it makes this process really slow (in my opinion, anyway). Just unpack your tarball and link it into your project as per [my article here](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2010/06/installing-symfony-without-pear/).

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. 
but I will get my teacher to report and correct this bug tomorrow. 
If it succeeds, I will report here. thx!

Comment: No probs. Bear in mind that, whatever it is, it won't get fixed either in Propel 1.2 or Symfony 1.0 - they are both well out of their maintenance cycles.

Comment: How did you get on? If you found this answer useful, please either tick it (it solved your problem) or +1 (it was helpful but didn't solve your problem).

Comment: sorry,I forgot to reply...
I can't solve this problem,so I'm coding my progmams on my server.

Comment: That's not recommended. All development should be done locally, so you have maximum control over your development environment (it also means you can use an IDE, and you get the speed of working on a local filesystem). Also, never do any coding on a live system - always work on a non-live copy.

Answer (score 0):

**Similar issue**

```
[wrapped: connect failed [Native Error: No such file or directory] [User Info: Array]]
```

Having had exactly the same issue with an old Symfony1 project at work, the fix that worked for me was to change the databases.yml from:-

```
mysql://root:@localhost/database_name_here
```

to

```
mysql://root:@127.0.0.1/database_name_here
```

The underlying issue for this was that the original dev environment was setup on Windows and my Dev environment is on a Mac. This may not be the same situation for you but hopefully will help someone out, searching for this error